# ¿Por qué no abre/escribe en el archivo cuando ejecuto el script por línea de comandos?

Tags: php, ssh, cron

He escrito un script PHP que me trae las páginas más visitadas en el día de hoy. Para no saturar las peticiones a la API de Google Analytics he pensado la siguiente estrategia:

- (a) Hacer una consulta a Google Analytics desde PHP cada una hora y escribir los resultados actualizados en un JSON
- (b) Usar ese JSON para presentar los datos cada vez que algún usuario entre en el sitio web

Para realizar lo indicado en (a), he pensado en escribir un archivo `bash` que haga una llamada al script PHP, y meter ese archivo `bash` en un cron job que se ejecute cada hora.

Dicho archivo `bash` sería prácticamente esto:

```
php ruta/mi-script.php
```

El contenido de `mi-script.php` sería básicamente este:

```
$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
$results = getTopPages($profile,$analytics);
$rows=$results["rows"];
$file = new SplFileObject(JSON_PATH.'results.json', "w");
$written = $file->fwrite(json_encode($rows,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto `php ruta/mi-script.php` desde la consola, el código de apertura del archivo JSON no funciona.

- No es problema de `mi-script.php`, ya que si lo ejecuto en el navegador funciona perfectamente.
- No es problema del uso de la API de Google Analytics, ya que si comento todo lo relativo al archivo y lo ejecuto desde la consola, me muestra las filas obtenidas por la API si hago por ejemplo `print_r($rows);`

El script, llamado desde la consola, deja de funcionar solamente cuando trato de abrir o escribir en el archivo.

También he probado a hacerlo con `file_put_contents` y con `fopen`, y **no funciona con niguna**.

**¿A qué se puede deber esto?  ¿Hay alguna forma de ejecutar el comando y que me informe sobre posibles errores?**

**NOTAS:**

- El entorno es un hosting compartido de BlueHost. Todo lo estoy haciendo con la cuenta main de cPanel.
- Cron Job funciona, pues tengo otros scripts bash que se ejecutan sin problema
- He tratado de crear el cron de esta forma: `/usr/php/54/usr/bin/php-cli /ruta/mi-script.php` y muchas otras más, pero no funciona.

Comment: ¿ Has tenido en cuenta que los usuarios bajo los que se ejecuta tu script son dinstintos ? Bajo el servidor web, eres el usuario www-data. Si lo ejecutas en cli, eres tu usuario real. Comprueba los permisos.

Comment: @Trauma pues resulta que era un error algo tonto, aunque todavía no entiendo por qué: en el script PHP yo hacía `include_once 'dirs.php';` Es un archivo donde defino algunas constantes, entre ellas `JSON_PATH` que es la ruta de mis archivos json. Pues no sé por qué **en la consola no reconocía ese `include` ni las constantes que hay en él**, lo cual resultaba en un error de ruta del archivo. Al poner la ruta absoluta ha funcionado. No entiendo por qué desde la consola no reconoce los valores definidos en el archivo que incluyo.