# ¿Como incluir wp-config.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy realizando un script en php y necesito incluir el wp-config.php de Wordpress, lo estoy haciendo de esta forma:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php';
```

Cuando ejecuto el script manualmente funciona bien, pero cuando lo hago a traves de un cron no. Alguien sabe a que se debe esto?. Gracias!

Comment: Tienes que ejecutar algo como esto o parecido en el cron: `/usr/php/7/usr/bin/php-cli /ruta/mi-script.php`  o sea, indicar la ruta donde se encuentra PHP y luego la ruta del archivo que ejecuta el include. ¿Lo estás haciendo así?

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes es probar a poner la ruta absoluta, yo tenía un problema parecido en un cron desde PHP y no funciona por ese motivo ([ver esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142786/29967) y los comentarios).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la forma en la que ejecuto el no es el problema porque lo he probado con otros scripts sencillos y funciona perfectamente. El problema se presenta cuando hago el include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php';